# Latest Project Template and Emulator for Bot Framework V3 throws 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: botframework

I created a project using the latest Bot Application Template (http://aka.ms/bf-bc-vstemplate)

I made sure that I installed the latest updates for Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition) and the nuget packages following the exact steps in the Getting Started page (http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html)

I also followed these steps since I'm testing it locally:

> When working with the emulator with a bot running locally, you need
>
> The Url for your bot set the localhost: pulled from the last
>   step. 
>   Note: will need to add the path "/api/messages" to your URL
>   when using the Bot Application template. Empty out the MicrosoftAppId
>   field Empty out the MicrosoftAppPassword field

I did a very basic test against the latest emulator(https://aka.ms/bf-bc-emulator) after running the Bot App project in VS 2015. When I send a "Typing" activity inside the Emulator, I received "500 Internal Server Error { "message":"An error has occurred." }".

But, when I place a comment on the BotAuthentication annotation

```
//[BotAuthentication]
```

Sending a "Typing" activity inside the emulator sends a "200 OK" response. Unfortunately, when I type in a word like "Hello" in the emulator, I get the "500 Internal Server Error { "message":"An error has occurred." }".

Any idea why this is happening?

Take note, I did not make any code changes to the default project except placing a comment to the BotAuthentication annotation.

The version of the Emulator is 3.0.0.54

**UPDATE:**
I see a **Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in mscorlib.dll** in VS Output window after the emulator shows "500 Internal Server Error { "message":"An error has occurred." }".

**UPDATE**

So I tried the exact setup in a different machine (Windows 8.1) because the machine I was working on is Win10 Evaluation. Guess what, it worked like a charm...so I guess it's an OS issue then or the GAC got messed up?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and i figure out the issue by putting a `try Catch` block in the `Post`method. The actual error pop

> Error in resolving Bot Id

I simply add a web config entry to my bot as below and it started working

```
 <add key="BotId" value="your app id"></add>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what versions you are using for the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime - 1.8.2
- Newtonsoft.Json - 8.0.3
- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt - 4.0.2.206221351

When I upgraded any of these to later versions, I see a 500 error when running in the emulator.

I also had to add the security information for my bot to Web.config.

```
<add key="BotId" value="<put your BotId here>" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="<put your AppId here>" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="<put your AppPassword here>" />
```

You will need to add the security info to the channel emulator.

Comment: thanks but that's already there by default when you create a Bot App project in VS

Comment: You need to add your BotId, MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword to these settings as well as the emulator.

Comment: again, as I mentioned on my post, since I am testing locally, the Url in the emulator was set to localhost,emptied out the MicrosoftAppId field and the MicrosoftAppPassword field in the emulator

Comment: I had the same problem initially with the emulator. In v1 I was able to leave the security settings blank in both my project and the emulator, but when I switched to v3 I had to put them in to get it working. Your issue may be different than mine, but I was not able to get the empty settings to work.

Comment: thanks for the inputs Bryan, but I also forgot to mention that I tried placing actual values for these keys too. I even tried to use the values that you get when you register the bots but it didn't help. Tried fake values as well. Did you try changing your V1 code that instead of doing a simple message.CreateReply , you used the V3 version of await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply)? - this is the default code in V3 projects. It seems like this is where its failing with the async call

Comment: Instead of porting my v1 code I just generated a new v3 project. I have not tried calling the v3 connector from my v1 code though. I do however see the call to ReplyToActivityAsync fail when I use the slack connector, but I suspect that this is unrelated to your issue. I posted an issue for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278845/replytoactivityasync-throwing-exception-with-slack-connector-on-bot-framework-v3

Comment: I just noticed that when I use the latest version of the rest client library I see a 500 error when running in the emulator. I added some info to the answer above.