# Bot Framework Channel Emulator (v3.0.0.58) Crashes After Launch

Tags: emulation, botframework

I have seen a few similar posts but not one quite like my issue.
Also, I don't have any other versions of the emulator installed.

I double-click the click-once installer, the app launches and then 
about 2 seconds after launch, it crashes with the following errors.

"Microsoft.Bot.Framework.Emulator has stopped working"

**View Problem Details**

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01: Bot Framework Channel Emulator
Problem Signature 02: 2.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03: 578e923b
Problem Signature 04: System
Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1075.0
Problem Signature 06: 56cfa343
Problem Signature 07: 364
Problem Signature 08: 73
Problem Signature 09: System.UriFormatException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID: 1033
Additional Information 1: 0a9e
Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3: 0a9e
Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

[image]

Comment: I had this problem, what I needed to do was to reset my PC.

Comment: Solved by deleting emulator.service file in %temp%
Problem caused when you upgrade from a previous version of emulator (v1) 
The emulator.service file did not get overwritten so v3 was using v1 settings, which were there previously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot i can see that Emulator Port and URL got changed. The Emulator port will always listen to port 9000, and the url should be `http://localhost:9000/`. Since the bot is crashing on its start, try remove the file `%temp%\emulator.service` from your temp folder and try restarting the emulator

You can also refer to link 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277691/latest-project-template-and-emulator-for-bot-framework-v3-throws-500-internal-se/38398742#38398742)
. and check the FAQ
[here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/)

Comment: cd %temp% >> del emulator.service